# Rigorous standardisation of data

Tags: statistics

I have 5 sets of raw experimental data + 1 control set and would like to know what you think about standardising/normalising each set. I want to compare the 5 sets of experimental data to the control set, so my first thought was to divide each data set by the mean $\mu$ of the control data. Would you do this?

Eg. Normalised set 1= set_1/mean(control)

It doesn't seem very rigorous and more importantly why choose this method as opposed to dividing my median, or $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}$?